# javascript jquery html - how to assign the title attribute to a .class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, title

I have a div that holds the results that is retrieved by ajax.  Depends on the result, the div will be assigned a different css class.  I want to attach the title attribute to the classes so that class 1 will show the title 1, and class 2 will show the title 2.  My routine is somewhat complicated, so assigning the `attr('title','xxx')` each time I switch the class has not been successful.

Is it possible to attach the title to a css class like the pseudo code below?

TIA

```
.class1
{
title: 'class1';

}

.class2
{
title: 'class2';

}
```

Comment: Your explanation is unclear. What do you mean that class 1 should *show* title 1? It should append new text? It should append a new node? It should make some "global" node visible? It should just have a particular value in the title attribute? Please provide specific examples of what you want. From where I'm sitting, `attr('title','xxx')` doesn't seem hard and shouldn't fail.

Comment: Can you provide the code where you specified `attr('title','xxx')`?

Answer (score 1):

Your explanation is a bit unclear, but you may want to try adding `live()` to the chain before you call `attr(title,xxx)`. AJAX requests (asynchronous ones) load data into the DOM after the onReady function executes your script, so whatever selector you are using may be invalid at the time the script executes.

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't.

CSS is designed to describe the *presentation* of a DOM, not its content (even though it dips a toe into that area with `content`).

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use only `attr(title,xxx)` Even if your routine is complex, you can do it in a line or 2 with jquery selectors